# Square root of a 2 by 2 matrix using MatrixPower[]

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix) a square root of a 2×2 matrix M is another 2×2 matrix R such that M = R^2. In general, there can be zero, two, four, or even an infinitude of square-root matrices.

I tried to use `MatrixPower` with `n=1/2` with a classic case of 4 solutions (determinant and trace are non zero) but it returns only one solution... (Mathematica 11.0)

```
MatrixPower[{{17, -16}, {-8, 9}}, 1/2]
(* return 1 solution {{11/3, -(8/3)}, {-(4/3), 7/3}} *)
```

What about the other 3 ? How to get the four of them ?

```
In:= MatrixPower[{{-3, 4}, {2, -1}}, 2]
In:= MatrixPower[{{3, -4}, {-2, 1}}, 2]
In:= MatrixPower[{{11/3, -(8/3)}, {-(4/3), 7/3}}, 2]
In:= MatrixPower[{{-(11/3), 8/3}, {4/3, -(7/3)}}, 2]
Out= {{17, -16}, {-8, 9}}
```

Of course, I can try `Solve[MatrixPower[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, 2] == {{17, -16}, {-8, 9}}, {a, b, c, d}]` and I'll get 4 solutions, but... why `MatrixPower` has such [undocumented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html) limitation ?

Does anybody know a clever command to overcome this behavior or should I write a dedicated function to handle these cases ?

Comment: By convention, when things like `Power[]` or `MatrixPower[]` are evaluated, only the [principal root](https://nhigham.com/2020/05/21/what-is-a-matrix-square-root/) is taken.

Comment: To put J.M.'s comment in other words, `Sqrt[4]` also only gives us one solution ($+2$) even though there are two ($+2$ and $-2$) available.

Comment: I would be aghast if `MatrixPower` returned anything other than a matrix; any other behavior would make it useless. So that "limitation" is  both by design and utterly necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The nice thing about *Mathematica* is that one can (almost) always go back to the definitions if in doubt. For evaluating non-principal roots, one can just go back to the Jordan decomposition of a matrix and change square root signs accordingly. To wit,

```
{sm, jm} = JordanDecomposition[{{17, -16}, {-8, 9}}];

Table[sm.DiagonalMatrix[d].Sqrt[jm].Inverse[sm], {d, Tuples[{1, -1}, 2]}]
   {{{11/3, -8/3}, {-4/3, 7/3}}, {{-3, 4}, {2, -1}},
    {{3, -4}, {-2, 1}}, {{-11/3, 8/3}, {4/3, -7/3}}}
```

Comment: N.B. I exploited here the fact that `jm` is actually diagonal. If `jm` had a Jordan block in it, things are not as straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an approach that's based on an answer I posted on Code Golf SE, with key assistance from member @att: [Calculate the integer square root of a matrix](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233050/104057)

I've removed the integer restriction, and the restriction to give only one solution.  I also added `RootReduce` to put the matrix elements into simpler form (this has no effect here, but can be helpful for solutions with radicals).  This will work for both diagonalizable and non-diagonalizable square matrices of any dimension.

```
m={{17,-16},{-8,9}};

(d=Length@#; q=Array[s,{d,d}])/.RootReduce@Solve[q.q==#]&@m
```

> { {{3, -4}, {-2, 1}},   {{11/3, -(8/3)}, {-(4/3), 7/3}},   {{-(11/3), 8/
> 3}, {4/3, -(7/3)}},   {{-3, 4}, {2, -1}} }

Using`Solve` makes it easy to filter solutions based on a domain restriction. E.g., this gives only integer solutions:

```
(d=Length@#; q=Array[s,{d,d}])/.RootReduce@Solve[q.q==#, Integers]&@m
```

> { {{-3, 4}, {2, -1}}, {{3, -4}, {-2, 1}} }