# Mathematica cannot find square roots of some matrices?

Tags: matrix

We know that

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)^2=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Why then Mathematica cannot find the square root of the later matrix? How to make it able to do it?

Comment: Likely because there are infinitely many matrices that, when squared, result in the latter matrix. How is Mathematica supposed to know you want that one instead of, e.g. `{{0,0,0,1/17},{17,0,13,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,17,0}}`?

Comment: @eyorble because the both are diagonal matrices, and isomorphic to formal power series, where this operation is well defined.

Comment: True, matrix square roots are not unique, but often MatrixPower[...,1/2] will return [one of them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239181/square-root-of-a-2-by-2-matrix-using-matrixpower).

Comment: @user293787 `MatrixPower[...,1/2]` uses power series and in the possible issues sections for `MatrixFunction` one sees that it will not work if the scalar function is not analytical at the eigenvalues. For a nilpotent matrix all of the eigenvalues are 0 and Sqrt is not analytic at 0.

Comment: @user293787 sorry I retract what I said, actually the documentation is not clear on this as it can still compute `MatrixPower[...,1/2]` for  a diagonal matrix with a 0 eigenvalue. I suppose that applies if the matrix is not diagonalizable and it needs to compute the power series. In any case power series will not work because one would have to apply Sqrt[1+(#-1)]& and for a Nilpotent matrix N, N-1 does not have a matrix norm smaller than 1.

Comment: @userrandrand `MatrixPower` can compute `Sign` function on matrices, which is obviously not analytic at zero.

Comment: That's peculiar as the possible issues section of MatrixFunction gives an example where `Abs` can not work and Sign is pretty much derived from `Abs`

Comment: @userrandrand the behavior of `Sign` is absolutely sane though. For complex $z$ represented as a matrix, it returns $z/|z|$, while for split-complex it returns value as if $a+bj$ was $a\pm b$, 9 possible values in total depending on whether $a$ and $b$ are greater than 0. For duals - the sign of the real part.

Comment: I tried `MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]` and it just gave formal derivatives of `Sign`

Comment: @userrandrand looks like a bug of evaluation of those derivatives, those should be evaluated to zero. The sign of this matrix is $1$ because all the eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: was the example you considered for `Sign` diagonal, diagonalizable or non diagonalizable ? It seems that for diagonal matrices `MatrixFunction` might skip the power series and apply directly the function to the diagonal components.

Comment: @userrandrand try `MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, 2},{3, 4}} ]`

Comment: `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}} // DiagonalizableMatrixQ`  evaluates to True and it works and   `{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}} // DiagonalizableMatrixQ` evaluates to False so when it is not diagonalizable it might by default apply a power series and if it is diagonalizable it does something else.

Comment: I am not sure how you interpreted `MatrixFunction[Sign, {{1, 2},{3, 4}} ]` as z/|z|. What is z/|z| for matrices ? If the eigenvalues are positive I would guess z.inv(Sqrt[z]^2)

Comment: @userrandrand matrix `{{1, 2},{3, 4}}` is not a complex number. It returns z/|z| for matrices, representing complex numbers, that is of the form $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 -b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Ohh quite nice so it respects the algebra for complex numbers on a matrix representation. In any case I think Mathematica is just applying the formula in section 7 of this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Matrix_functions

Comment: @user293787 sorry but as my messages before were confusing I should maybe just mention that I think that everything is clear if we consider that Mathematica is just applying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Matrix_functions.

Comment: @userrandrand No problem. I think your more recent comment, matrix functions defined in terms of the Jordan normal form, seems most relevant.

Answer (score 9):

A brute force approach is possible:

```
A = Array[a, {4, 4}];

rhs = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}, 2];

eqns = A . A == rhs // LogicalExpand;

solns = Solve[Reduce[eqns]];

Length[solns]
(* 3 *)

MatrixForm /@ Simplify[A /. solns]
```

[image]

Verify that these do indeed solve the equation

```
A . A == rhs /. solns // Simplify
(* {True, True, True} *)
```

The first solution is a function of 4 parameters.  Clearly, the second solution is simply the special case of the first with `a[4,4]->0`.  I wonder if the third is a special limiting case of the first, but I haven't tried too hard to find it.

Some clues are available as to why Mathematica fails with more direct approaches.  For example

```
MatrixFunction[Sqrt, rhs, Method -> "Jordan"]
(* MatrixFunction::fnanc: The function Sqrt[#1]& is not analytic at 0. *)
(* MatrixFunction[Sqrt, {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, Method -> "Jordan"] *)
```

In fact, `MatrixFunction` documentation states

> MatrixFunction does not return a result when the scalar function or any of its initial derivatives are not defined at matrix eigenvalues

In this case, we have

```
Eigenvalues[rhs]
(* {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: (sorry for so many edits). I think Mathematica just uses the formula on this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Matrix_functions. In particular, that would explain why Mathematica can find a square root of `{{1,0},{0,0}}` even though it has a zero eigenvalue.

Answer (score 7):

**Edit**

- Since there are many 4*4 matrix satisfies such matrix equation `m^2==m1`,we use `FindInstance` to find one of such `m`.

```
m = Array[a, {4, 4}];
m1 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 3}] -> 1, {4, 4}];
m1//MatrixForm
sol = FindInstance[MatrixPower[m, 2] == m1, Flatten@m, Integers]
m /. sol[[1]]
```

> {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}

- If we remove the `Integers` in above code, we get

> {{0, 0, -1, -1}, {-1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}}

It gave another example which satisfies the original matrix equation.

**Original**

```
FindInstance[
 MatrixPower[Array[a, {4, 4}], 2] == 
  SparseArray[Band[{1, 3}] -> 1, {4, 4}], 
 Flatten@Array[a, {4, 4}], Integers]
Array[a, {4, 4}] /. %[[1]]
```

Comment: What is this code even supposed to do?

Comment: OK, modified the code to this: `MSqrt[A_] := 
 Array[a, {Length[A], Length[A]}] /. 
  FindInstance[
    MatrixPower[Array[a, {Length[A], Length[A]}] m, 2] == A, 
    Flatten@m, Integers][[1]]` (do not know how to remove intermediate variable)

Comment: With `Integers` the code fails on matrices which have no integer roots, and without it it gives undesirable answer in the example from the OP.

Comment: @Anixx  For some matrix, the `1/2` power work. `MatrixPower[{{2, 3, 0}, {4, 9, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}, 1/2]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an optimization approach where I minimize the square error between $A^2$ and $B$, regularized with the 1-norm to encourage sparse solutions.:

$$
\underset{A_{ij}}{\mathrm{argmin}}\left(\left\Vert \mathrm{vec}(A^2-B)\right\Vert_2+\lambda\cdot \left\Vert \mathrm{vec}(A)\right\Vert_1\right)
$$

```
objective[X_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ]&), Y_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ]&)] := Norm[Flatten[X.X-Y], 2]

regularizer[X_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ]&)] := Norm[Flatten@X,1];

b = {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
A = Array[a, {4, 4}];
result = With[{λ = 0.1},
    NMinimize[objective[A, b] + λ*regularizer[A], Flatten[A], 
     Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
    ] // Last;

tolerance = 1*^-7;
(a1 = Chop[A /. result, tolerance]) // MatrixForm
Chop[b1 = a1 . a1, tolerance] // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1.42473 \\
 -0.701888 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -0.701888 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$